# MacRuby Pointer to typedef struct

Tags: ruby, cocoa, pointers, rubymotion, macruby

this code fails with Semgentation Fault: 11, and I can't understand why

```
framework 'Cocoa'
framework 'CoreFoundation'
framework 'Security'
* keychainObject = Pointer.new_with_type('^{OpaqueSecKeychainRef}')
SecKeychainOpen("/Users/charbon/Library/Keychains/Josja.keychain",keychainObject)
SecKeychainLock(keychainObject)
```

I'm sure it has to do with the keychainObject type, because this works  (it locks the default keychain).

```
SecKeychainLock(nil)
```

I'm using the '^{OpaqueSecKeychainRef}' as the type of pointer because that's what the debugger told me it expected when I used a wrong type of pointer.

*I hope solving this would help grasping the macruby / cocoa magic.*

For reference, the complete output is

```
cobalt:~ charbon$ macirb Desktop/test.rb 
irb(main):001:0> framework 'Cocoa'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> framework 'CoreFoundation'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> framework 'Security'
=> true
irb(main):004:0> * keychainObject = Pointer.new_with_type('^{OpaqueSecKeychainRef}')
=> [#<Pointer:0x4007ac200>]
irb(main):005:0> SecKeychainOpen("/Users/charbon/Library/Keychains/Josja.keychain",keychainObject)
=> 0
irb(main):006:0> SecKeychainLock(keychainObject)
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were writing C you would have written

```
SecKeychainRef keyChainRef;
SecKeychainOpen("/path/to/...", &keychainRef);
SecKeychainLock(keyChainRef);
```

i.e. while SecKeychainOpen requires a pointer to a `SecKeychainRef` (so that the output parameter can be filled in), other apis just require a `SecKeychainRef`, so you need to dereference the pointer:

```
framework 'Security'
keychainObject = Pointer.new_with_type('^{OpaqueSecKeychainRef}')
SecKeychainOpen("/Users/charbon/Library/Keychains/Josja.keychain",keychainObject)
SecKeychainLock(keychainObject.value)
```

Comment: Thanks Fred for shiming in ! Should'nt the third line be with a * before keychainObject ? SecKeychainOpen("/Users/charbon/Library/Keychains/Josja.keychain",*keychainObject)

Comment: Nope. * in ruby is something completely different

Comment: All right, got it, thanks. Posted the "reverse" question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902293/macruby-pointer-referencing-dereferencing-when-using-cocoa-frameworks