# MacRuby pointer, referencing, dereferencing when using Cocoa Frameworks

Tags: objective-c, ruby, cocoa, pointers, macruby

On [MacRuby Pointer to typedef struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899102/macruby-pointer-to-typedef-struct), I learnt how to dereference a pointer created with

```
x=Pointer.new_with_type
...
==> use x.value, or x[0]
```

Works a treat !

Now I want to learn what I believe to be the "opposite". I'm trying to use this API.

```
OSStatus SecKeychainCopySettings (
   SecKeychainRef keychain,
   SecKeychainSettings *outSettings
);
```

Second parameter must be a Pointer. But I never manage to get the real outSettings of the keychain opened, I only get the default settings.

```
framework 'Security'
keychainObject = Pointer.new_with_type('^{OpaqueSecKeychainRef}')
SecKeychainOpen("/Users/charbon/Library/Keychains/Josja.keychain",keychainObject)

#attempt #1
settings=Pointer.new_with_type('{SecKeychainSettings=IBBI}')
SecKeychainCopySettings(keychainObject.value, settings)
p settings.value
#<SecKeychainSettings version=0 lockOnSleep=false useLockInterval=false lockInterval=0>

#attempt #2
settings2=SecKeychainSettings.new
result = SecKeychainCopySettings(keychainObject.value, settings2)
p settings2
#<SecKeychainSettings version=0 lockOnSleep=false useLockInterval=false lockInterval=0>
```

The settings of the Keychain opened should read

```
#<SecKeychainSettings version=0 lockOnSleep=true useLockInterval=true lockInterval=1800>
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it !
The doc to SecKeychainCopySettings mentions

> outSettings
>   On return, a pointer to a keychain settings structure.
>   Since this structure is versioned, you must allocate the memory for it
>   and fill in the version of the structure before passing it to the
>   function.

So we can't just create a Pointer to SecKeychainSettings. We must set the version of the Struct that is pointed by the pointer to to something.

```
settings=Pointer.new_with_type('{SecKeychainSettings=IBBI}')
#settings[0] dereferences the Pointer
#for some reason, settings[0][0]=1 does not work, nor settings[0].version=1
settings[0]=[1,false,false,0]
#we are redefining the complete SecKeychainSettings struct
# [0]=version [1]=lockOnSleep [2]=useLockInterval [3]=lockInterval
result = SecKeychainCopySettings(keychainObject.value, settings)
p settings
=> #<SecKeychainSettings version=1 lockOnSleep=true useLockInterval=false lockInterval=300> irb(main):019:0>
```